# Ball in magnetic field, not understanding boundary condition

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, magnetic-fields

So I am reading solution of following exercise:

A conducting sphere with radius $R$ moves with constant velocity $v=ve_x$ inside a constant magnetic field $B=Be_y$. Find the induced charge distribution on the sphere to 1st order in $v/c$ in the laboratory inertial reference frame.
Which is on page:
https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/moving-sphere-in-magnetic-field.825426/
So the personal is this topic solves laplace equation with condition that potenial w infinity must go to $-r\gamma \frac{v}{c}\cos\theta$ I don't get why.

Answer (score 0):

Because it implements the correct boundary conditions for the electric field in the primed reference system $E'(r) \to E_0\vec{e}_z$. Check that this is true by taking the gradient.

Conversely you may ask what potential fulfills $\nabla \Phi(r,\theta) = E_0\vec{e}_z$ which will lead to the expression.

Admittedly, it is not obvious at first glance and the author of the question probably put some thought into it.